# ribbon menu command search in vsto

Tags: excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx

The search function is used in EXCEL to search for the specified menu command.
like this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJTOX.png

If the button developed by VSTO needs to implement an interface, it can be searched.
This interface forgets which I am.

MSDN can't find it, let me know if you know, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all features of the ribbon are available for developers. The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for that. You can find the definitive list of controls and customizations described in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Nothing has been changed since Office 2007.

You may try using the [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) to automate tasks related to the user interface in Office applications.